# Relation between First Brillouin Zone and primitive cell in real space

Tags: solid-state-physics, fourier-transform, crystals

Let's say that I have built the [Wigner-Seitz cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%E2%80%93Seitz_cell) of a crystal in the real space. Is it correct to say that now, if I Fourier transform it, I obtain the First Brillouin Zone in the $k$-space?

Comment: Fourier transform what?

Comment: the weigner-seitz cell

Comment: Can you write down what exactly you mean in mathematical terms?

Comment: I don't know how to write it down. I know that the reciprocal lattice is the Fourier transform of the real lattice, and the first Brillouin zone is the weigner-seitz cell obtained in the reciprocal space. If I'm in the real space, and I have the geometry of the Weigner-seitz cell in the real space, is it correct to say that if I Fourier transform this cell I will obtain the 1st Brillouin zone in the reciprocal space?

Answer (score 0):

Reciprocal lattice is fourier transform of real lattice and first Brillouin zone is the wigner seitz cell of reciprocal lattice.

Answer (score 0):

The $k$ values in the first Brillouin zone are smaller than a reciprocal lattice vector. This implies that they correspond to wavelengths *greater* than the lattice spacing. The first Brillouin zone tells you what changes between real space unit cells, not what is happening within them.